# SHA1 key problem when need to test Google Firebase Authentication with 3 Firebase projects - React native

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, sha1

I am working on Google Firebase Authentication and use 3 .env variables (dev, staging, production) and use react-native-config to manage. Then I create 3 firebase projects (my-project, my-project-stg, my-project-prod).

The problem is I can add the SHA1 key with only 1 project but I want to add to others to test all authentication environments. How can I resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same SHA-1 as many times as you want, as long as the application ID is different between each of the projects.

In other words, only the **pair** of SHA-1 and application ID must be unique per project.

Comment: So, What if my two projects(Staging-Production) needs to use same package name(App id) & SHA-1 pair ? 
Should I simply create another keystore for staging ?